# Express.js server with Apache Tomcat

Tags: javascript, node.js, tomcat, express

I am making a sample web application in node.js using express.js. I am getting a little confused when using apache-tomcat as my web server. I have two doubts:

1. When i run apache-tomcat as a web server and my express.js server is providing me services at port number 4000, how does it know at which port to listen to tomcat web server. and what if i have multiple instances of tomcat running on localhost, how will it know which instance of the server to connect to.

   ```
   app.listen(port, "127.0.0.1");
   ```
2. And how does the following line of code works:

   ```
   var server = app.listen(4000, function() {

       var host = server.address().address;
       var port = server.address().port;

       console.log('server listeninig at http://%s:%s', host, port);
   });
   ```
3. Why do we need to take help of apache tomcat or other web servers if we can provide web services using express.js only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that combining express.js (simple web server for Node.JS platform) and Apache Tomcat (Servlet container from JVM world) make sense at all.

I bet that you are confusing [Apache Web Server](http://httpd.apache.org/) with [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/). They are two completely separate projects. If that is the case than notice that [Apache Web Server](http://httpd.apache.org/) or [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) HTTP servers are often used with express.js as [reverse proxies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). This combination is often used to match security and performance (e.g. caching) requirements needed for PROD grade app.

To answer your question, no don't combine express.js with Apache Tomcat. If you are just starting playing with express.js, use it standalone. If it turns to be a app that should run in production, you will need to operationalize it, which would probably include considerations around combining it with some HTTP server.

Comment: Hi, I am still confused about how does express know on which port to listen to tomcat ?

Comment: Wipe out tomcat from equation. Standalone Express.JS will serve you well for learning purposes.

Comment: Your app is listening on port 4000 so fire HTTP requests against localhost:4000 when you start your express server

Comment: This blog post is using Apache Web Server (HTTP server), not Apache Tomcat (Servlet container). There is bog difference between these two.